# How to implement a vertically scrolling listview and another horizontally and vertically scrolling listview in same layout

Tags: android, layout, android-listview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I want to create a layout in which there are two listviews.I want the first one to be scrolled vertically.The second listview need to be scrolled both horizontally and vertically.And finally both these listviews to be scrolled together vertically as a whole.How to do this ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? You question is not very clear. How do you imagine a both vertically and horizontally scrolling `ListView`?

Comment: @MarkBuikema its like a Listview which contains data which has width more than the currently visible screen.so i want to put a horizontal scroll so that i can scroll horizontally and can view it.Vertical scroll also need to be implemented to view the listview items in each row.

Comment: I doubt this would be the best design choice but you would have to put the second `ListView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: I tried that.But the width of listview is getting reduced like this http://i.imgur.com/mGp8kOV.png.My requirement is that first listview should be the exact size as in the image and second one should fill the remaining area.You got my question ?